# Choosing an RDN for new objectClasses in LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi, openldap, adam

What are the best practices for choosing an RDN when creating new objectClasses in LDAP? I know you can choose from uid, cn, ou, and so on, but what practices should one follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RDN is essentially (part of) your primary key. The same principles apply:

- Something unique about the entry (or a combination of things).
- Something that doesn't change (or doesn't change very often).

Comment: Note that [Findley's "LDAP Best Practices" paper, section 3.5](http://people.apache.org/~elecharny/ldapcon/Andrew%20Findlay-paper.pdf) encourages using a unique identifier in the RDN.

Answer (score 3):

When using OpenLDAP you can choose any attribute as RDN that is allowed on the object (according to its objectClasses) but on ActiveDirectory the [RDN attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223167.aspx) is defined in the appropriate schema - so you don't have a choice when using pre-defined classes.

When you have the choice (using OpenLDAP or using your own schema on ActiveDirectory), I'd suggest to use a RDN that effectively identifies the underlying entry (naturally your RDN must be unique within the children of a given subtree). OpenLDAP also allows for the use of multi-valued RDNs if you determine a single RDN-attribute is not sufficient to uniquely identify a given entry:

```
cn=Robert Smith+uid=rsmith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it may be more wise to use one of the pre-defined objectClasses instead of creating a new one. [Here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/) is a list of commonly used derived classes.